# Поиск значения в ListBox /DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf

Как найти определённое значение в листбоксе или таблице, к которой он привязан? Есть, например, таблица

```
поля фио <...ещё что-то...>
```

и меня интересует номер, например, Васи Питерского - как мне получить его номер и в листбоксе его выделить?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (ListBoxItem item in <Ваш ListBox>)
{
    if (item.<нужное_поле>.Equals(<ключ_поиска>) {
        item.selected = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

точно синтаксис у ListBox'а не помню, но Вам нужно что-то подобное.